# Firebase gives error when trying to enable offline persistence

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I'm trying to enable offline persistence on a web app with `Nuxt.js`. However, I get an error:

```
Error enabling offline persistence. Falling back to persistence disabled: FirebaseError: [code=unimplemented]: 
This platform is either missing IndexedDB or is known to have an incomplete implementation. 
Offline persistence has been disabled.
```

My code in the `firebase.js` in the `plugins` directory is:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const config = {
        apiKey: '',
        authDomain: '',
        databaseURL: '',
        projectId: '',
        storageBucket: '',
        messagingSenderId: '',
        appId: '',
        measurementId: ''
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)

const fireDb = firebase.firestore();
fireDb.enablePersistence()
  .catch(function(err) {
      if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
          // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
          // in one tab at a a time.
          // ...
          console.log(err.code);
      } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
          // The current browser does not support all of the
          // features required to enable persistence
          // ...
          console.log(err.code);
      }
  });



export{fireDb}
```

How can I fix this error? It should be noted that reading from or writing to firestore works fine

Comment: Is this code meant to be running server-side? If so, this is expected as there is no persistence implementation in the Firebase SDK for server-side platforms.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen didn't get a notification for your comment. But no this is intended to be executed on the client. I've figured it out however, I'll write an answer soon

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I could use your expertise on another issue if you'll oblige me.
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926389/firebase-cloud-messaging-not-working-with-samsung-internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Nuxt has both server and client side execution. If you want something to be executed on the client side alone (in javascript) you have to wrap it in process.browser.

```
if(process.browser){
fireDb.enablePersistence()
  .catch(function(err) {
      if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
          // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
          // in one tab at a a time.
          // ...
          console.log(err.code);
      } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
          // The current browser does not support all of the
          // features required to enable persistence
          // ...
          console.log(err.code);
      }
  });
}
```

Note that if you're initializing firebase cloud messaging you'd have to take the same approach.

If you had some html or a component you'd have to wrap it in `<client-only></client-only>` since no-ssr has been deprecated